# Issue In Cassandra Connection using Spark in Java

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect to cassandra from Spark using sparkcassandraconnector and sparkcassandraconnectorjava. I am able to connect to spark master but connecting to Cassandra is failing with below ERROR. Can someone please guide me how to fix this. Is this a Jar issue.
I am using below dependency to implement this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**ERROR ->**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$CassandraSSLConf$.apply$default$6(CassandraConnectorConf.scala:47)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.(CassandraConnectorConf.scala:114)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf$.(CassandraConnectorConf.scala)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:192)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD$.apply(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:285)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.SparkContextJavaFunctions.cassandraTable(SparkContextJavaFunctions.java:94)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.SparkContextJavaFunctions.cassandraTable(SparkContextJavaFunctions.java:70)

Comment: What is the Cassandra DB version you are using? Please check the compatibility of versions at https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Comment: I am using DSE 4.8.8